# Changing image src to display an array of images using two buttons

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and trying to write a script to change the url of an image on my website back and forth using two buttons.

I somehow managed to do the forward stepping one, using the code below, but can't figure out how to do the same backwards.

```js
var trafficlights = [
  'images/csp-1.png',
  'images/csp-2.png',
  'images/csp-3.png',
  'images/csp-4.png',
  'images/csp-5.png',
  'images/csp-6.png',
  'images/csp-7.png',
  'images/csp-8.png',

];
var num = 1

function lightsequence() {
  document.getElementById('my-image').src = trafficlights[num++ % trafficlights.length];
}
```

```html
<div class="tap-control-buttons">
  <button id="previous" onclick="lightsequence2()"> <img src="images/left.png"> </button>
  <button id="next" onclick="lightsequence()"> <img src="images/right.png"> </button>
</div>


<img class="tap-image " id="my-image" src="images/csp-1.png">
```

Any leads greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the length to the new number before the modulo to loop back, so:

```
num = (num-- + trafficlights.length) % trafficlights.length
```

This also doesn't break incrementing forward, so you can use one function:

```js
var trafficlights = [
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Z%C3%A9ro.svg/120px-Z%C3%A9ro.svg.png',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/Un1.svg/120px-Un1.svg.png',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/Deux.svg/120px-Deux.svg.png',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Trois.svg/120px-Trois.svg.png'
];
var num = 0

function lightsequence(increment) {
  num = (num + increment + trafficlights.length) %trafficlights.length
  document.getElementById('my-image').src = trafficlights[num];
}
```

```html
<div class="tap-control-buttons">
  <button id="previous" onclick="lightsequence(-1)"> Back </button>
  <button id="next" onclick="lightsequence(1)"> Next
</div>


<img class="tap-image " id="my-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Z%C3%A9ro.svg/120px-Z%C3%A9ro.svg.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can eliminate the inline JS by attaching a listener to the buttons' parent element which can catch events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM (known as [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)). Check that the child element is a button, and then run the rest of the function.
2. Check which button fired the click event by its `id`. If it's "previous" reduce `num`; "next", increase `num`.

```js
const trafficlights=["https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=Light","https://dummyimage.com/50x50/aaa/000&text=Light","https://dummyimage.com/50x50/456/fff&text=Light","https://dummyimage.com/50x50/ff0/000&text=Light","https://dummyimage.com/50x50/9a4/000&text=Light","https://dummyimage.com/50x50/1a5/fff&text=Light"];

// Cache the elements
const image = document.querySelector('.tap-image');
const buttons = document.querySelector('.tap-control-buttons');

// Add a listener to the containing element
buttons.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

let num = 0;

function handleClick(e) {
  
  // If the child element that fired the event
  // is a button...
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    
    // ...destructure its id
    const { id } = e.target;
    
    // ...decrease/increase the value of `num` within the
    // bounds of the array
    if (id === 'previous' && num > 0) --num;
    if (id === 'next' && num < trafficlights.length - 1) ++num;
    
    // Set the new image
    image.src = trafficlights[num];
  }

}
```

```css
.tap-image { margin-top: 1em; }
.tap-control-buttons button { font-size: 1.2em; border-radius: 5px; }
.tap-control-buttons button:hover { background-color: lightblue; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="tap-control-buttons">
  <button id="previous"></button>
  <button id="next"></button>
</div>

<img class="tap-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=Light">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something too complicated for what you need.

An array has indexes (read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), so you only need to keep track of the current index and then update it after changing the image.

Something like:

```
var trafficlights = ['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png'];
var currentIndex = 0

function goingUp() {
  document.getElementById('my-image').src = trafficlights[currentIndex+1];
}

function goingDown() {
  document.getElementById('my-image').src = trafficlights[currentIndex-1];
}
```

Of course, you need to keep in mind the edge cases: if the current index is the last or the first one. This would be a working code:

```
var trafficlights = ['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png'];
var currentIndex = 0

function goingUp() {
  // if the current index is the last one
  if (currentIndex === trafficlights.length - 1) {
      // we update the index to the first one
      currentIndex = 0;
  } else {
     // otherwise, we just add one
     currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
  }
  // and then apply this new index to get the next image
  document.getElementById('my-image').src = trafficlights[currentIndex];
}

function goingDown() {
  // if the current index is the first one
  if (currentIndex === 0) {
      // we update the index to the last one
      currentIndex = trafficlights.length - 1;
  } else {
     // otherwise, we just substract one
     currentIndex = currentIndex - 1;
  }
  document.getElementById('my-image').src = trafficlights[currentIndex];
}
```